# Is youtube data api paging consistent if you use pagetokens? (v3 data api)

Tags: youtube-api

The YouTube V3 Data API provides "page tokens" for paging result sets from search endpoints.

Is the dataset being viewed consistent if you make use of the page tokens?

e.g. if there is an ordering on view count, which is likely to change with time, then is the ordering over the total result set guaranteed across multiple queries, so the lowest result on the first page is guaranteed to be ordered greater than the highest result on the following page?

Comment: I'll ask around internally to confirm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ordering is not guaranteed when using page tokens. (Nor was it guaranteed when using start-index in v1/v2.) If something changes with the backend data source's ordering in between fetching one page and the next page, then retrieving the next page would reflect the updated ordering.

Comment: Thanks Jeff - the change over to alphanumeric tokens made me wonder if they were referencing transaction ids/cache entries, but it seems they're just a straight replacement for the start index.