# Youtube Data API v3 Search Results Ranking

Tags: youtube-api

I am using Youtube api V3 to get the Youtube ranking, but after reading this post [Is youtube data api paging consistent if you use pagetokens? (v3 data api)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175190/is-youtube-data-api-paging-consistent-if-you-use-pagetokens-v3-data-api)
I realized that the ordering is not guaranteed when using page tokens, so there is any option to get the same order? for example for the first 300 entries, Can I get it trough the API (order by relevance and using the same configuration settings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using page tokens is the suggested best way to retrieve further results. Even though there is not a 100% guarantee, you will still get the same most likely.