# Unexpected behaviour while paging with youtube API V3 [Google APIs Client Library for Python]

Tags: python, youtube-api

Using the Google APIs Client Library for Python and the search endpoint API V3 did the follwing query:

```
search_response = youtube.search().list(
                        q="Mallorca",
                        part="id,snippet",
                        maxResults=50,
                        order="date",
                        publishedBefore="2014-1-1T2:00:00Z",
                        publishedAfter="2014-1-1T1:00:00Z",
                    ).execute()
```

The response shows a `search_response.pageInfo.totalResults` of 186. That means that paging is needed to retrieve all results. However in this response I get only one result (one video) under `search_response.items` instead of the expected 50 of the first page.

If I use the `nextPageToken` (=CDIQAA) to query for the next results page:

```
search_response = youtube.search().list(
                        q="Mallorca",
                        part="id,snippet",
                        maxResults=50,
                        order="date",
                        publishedBefore="2014-1-1T2:00:00Z",
                        publishedAfter="2014-1-1T1:00:00Z",
                        pageToken= "CDIQAA"
                    ).execute()
```

I obtain again only one result, the same video (same `videoId`) retrieved at the first query. Same thing happens when I navigate through the next pages of the `search_response` until no more pages are available (`nextPageToken`not included in the response).

Have read this previous question:

[page tokens use youtube api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837516/page-tokens-use-youtube-api-v3)

and this:

[Is youtube data api paging consistent if you use pagetokens? (v3 data api)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175190/is-youtube-data-api-paging-consistent-if-you-use-pagetokens-v3-data-api)

but they don't explain why I get only one result, the same video for all pages delivered by the response.

Is this an issue of the youtube API or I am doing something wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like this is an open issue for the youtube API:

[issue 5173](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5173)

Comment: Yes, you are right, follow the issue. For now you can avoid ordering to get right results, but issue should get fixed soon.

Comment: Thank you very much @IbrahimUlukaya, I will close this question and follow the issue as you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an open issue for the youtube API:

[issue 5173](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5173)

Expected to be fixed soon...

The right results can be obtained if ordering is not applied.