# Youtube API - search by topicId stops at page 19

Tags: node.js, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there any reason why after 19 search requests for videos with the topicId `/m/019_rr`, the API sends an `undefined` nextPageToken?

[image: the log of nextPageTokens and the result for the last request]

As it can be seen in the screenshot, the nextPageToken for the last request is `undefined` and the result for that request is also logged showing that it has an empty list of items.

The first request's `pageInfo` property says:

```
"pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1000000,
    "resultsPerPage": 50
},
```

So this means there surely must be more than 20 requests to be made.

The requests options I use are:

```
{
    part: 'snippet',
    maxResults: 50,
    topicId: '/m/019_rr',
    pageToken: nextPageToken || '',
    regionCode: 'US',
    key: config.googleApiKey
}
```

I am also sure this is not a quota issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You may check this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110625/unexpected-behaviour-while-paging-with-youtube-api-v3-google-apis-client-librar) wherein it stated that the right results can be obtained if ordering is not applied. Check this [reported issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35173543) for updates.

Comment: @abielita As can be seen from the initial question, I don't use any ordering, so the order will default to "relevance". But the problem still persists.